# Cordova geolocation deploy

Tags: cordova

I encounter a problem with a new project i started. I must develop a mobile app and the chosen technology is Apache Cordova. I'va make many test before to develop, i have problems. I've not found answers to my questions (with docs or someone with the same errors).

First, the target is Android device and i've loaded the org.apache.cordova.geolocation module (cordova plugin add in CLi)

When i try to test on ripple emulator (Chrome 37 & nodejs module), i can have my position (when i accept to browser to give my position) but not the position defined in the frame Geo Locate. Is it normal ? When i reload, nothing new. The only thing append is that the inspector give me a 404 to config.xml file.

When i run it on my android device with the location on, i can't have my position and no error.

Can someone explain me how to do it so it works ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The geolocation module was removed from cordova's project.
So two solutions : downgrade or use the browser implementations.